# I dont understand this for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Code below

```
    game = [[0,0,0],
            [0,0,0],
            [0,0,0]]

    print('   0  1  2')

    for count, row in enumerate(game):
        print(count, row)
```

Outputs below

```
       0  1  2
    0 [0, 0, 0]
    1 [0, 0, 0]
    2 [0, 0, 0]
```

What exactly is count and row? What exactly are they referencing.
I understand that enumerate will add the number before each list.

Comment: `enumerate(items)` returns `(index, item)`. You can read about [What does enumerate do ?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) from the docs, and they have a good example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count is index number for each element in a list, row is printing the elements of the list.

You have 3 elements inside your game list. Index starts with 0 so it is getting you:
0
1
2

try this code below for more practice:

```
for index, items in enumerate(game[0]):
    print(index, items)

output is
0 0 
1 0
2 0
```

this is giving you the items of the first list inside the game list with index numbers. Good Luck

Comment: Pardon me if not not using the correct terms. So, does the first variable, 'index' in this case, always refer to the index of a list?

Comment: Yes, you got it correct, if you make for loop like, for james, peng in enumerate(game):. In this case james is always the index and peng will get you th elements.